# Standard method of getting containing box?

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

OK, if I have the following shapes that are rotated and then selected you will see their bounding boxes:
[image]

I am trying to write some code to align objects with respect to each other. So I would like to get each object's "containing box".

I am aware of `getBoundingRect` but, for the above shapes this gives me the following:
[image]

As such, these boxes are not that useful to me. Is there a standard method of getting what I would call the "containing boxes" for all shapes? For example, I would like to be able to have the following boxes returned to me:
[image]

So, for any given shape I would like to be able get the red bounding rectangle (with no rotation).

Obviously, I could write a routine for each possible shape within fabricJS but I would prefer not to reinvent the wheel! Any ideas?

*Edit* Here's an interactive snippet that shows the current bounding boxes (in red):

```js
$(function () 
{
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

    canvas.add(new fabric.Triangle({
      left: 50,
      top: 50,
      fill: '#FF0000',
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      angle : 30
    }));

    canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
      left: 250,
      top: 50,
      fill: '#00ff00',
      radius: 50,
      angle : 30
    }));

    canvas.add(new fabric.Polygon([
      {x: 185, y: 0},
      {x: 250, y: 100},
      {x: 385, y: 170},
      {x: 0, y: 245} ], {
        left: 450,
        top: 50,
        fill: '#0000ff',
        angle : 30
      }));

    canvas.on("after:render", function(opt) 
    { 
        canvas.contextContainer.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
        canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) 
        {
            var bound = obj.getBoundingRect();

            canvas.contextContainer.strokeRect(
                bound.left + 0.5,
                bound.top + 0.5,
                bound.width,
                bound.height
            );
        });
    });

    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.6/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="600"></canvas><br/>
```

Comment: Are the actual shapes svg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue and I found a workaround. I created a temporary SVG from the active object and placed it outside the viewport. Then I measured the real bounding box using the native [getBBox()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox) function.

**UPDATE**

Apparently, the solution above works only in Firefox (76), so I came up with a different solution. Since I couldn't find a properly working, native function to get the real bounding box of a shape, I decided to scan the pixels and retrieve the boundaries from there.

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/divpusher/2m7c61gw/118/

**How it works:**

- export the selected fabric object [toDataURL()](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#toDataURL)
- place it in a hidden canvas and get the pixels with [getImageData()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData)
- scan the pixels to retrieve x1, x2, y1, y2 edge coords of the shape

**Demo below**

```js
// ---------------------------
// the magic

var tempCanv, ctx, w, h;

function getImageData(dataUrl) { 
  // we need to use a temp canvas to get imagedata
  if (tempCanv == null) {
    tempCanv = document.createElement('canvas');
    tempCanv.style.border = '1px solid blue';
    tempCanv.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    ctx = tempCanv.getContext('2d');
   document.body.appendChild(tempCanv);
 }
    
 return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   if (dataUrl == null) return reject();    
    
    var image = new Image();
    image.addEventListener('load', function() {
      w = image.width;
      h = image.height;
      tempCanv.width = w;
      tempCanv.height = h;
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, w, h);
      var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, w, h).data.buffer;         
   resolve(imageData, false);      
    });
    image.src = dataUrl;
 });
  
}

function scanPixels(imageData) {
 var data = new Uint32Array(imageData),
      len = data.length,
      x, y, y1, y2, x1 = w, x2 = 0;
  
  // y1
  for(y = 0; y < h; y++) {
    for(x = 0; x < w; x++) {
      if (data[y * w + x] & 0xff000000) {
        y1 = y;
        y = h;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  
  // y2
  for(y = h - 1; y > y1; y--) {
    for(x = 0; x < w; x++) {
      if (data[y * w + x] & 0xff000000) {
        y2 = y;
        y = 0;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  // x1
  for(y = y1; y < y2; y++) {
    for(x = 0; x < w; x++) {
      if (x < x1 && data[y * w + x] & 0xff000000) {
        x1 = x;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  // x2
  for(y = y1; y < y2; y++) {
    for(x = w - 1; x > x1; x--) {
      if (x > x2 && data[y * w + x] & 0xff000000) {
        x2 = x;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  
  return {
   x1: x1,
    x2: x2,
    y1: y1,
    y2: y2
  }
}



// ---------------------------
// align buttons

function alignLeft(){
 var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  obj.set('left', 0);
  obj.setCoords();
  canvas.renderAll();
}


function alignLeftbyBoundRect(){
 var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  var bound = obj.getBoundingRect();
  obj.set('left', (obj.left - bound.left));
  obj.setCoords();
  canvas.renderAll();
}

function alignRealLeft(){
 var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
  getImageData(obj.toDataURL())
   .then(function(data) {    
     var bound = obj.getBoundingRect();
     var realBound = scanPixels(data);  
      obj.set('left', (obj.left - bound.left - realBound.x1));      
      obj.setCoords();
      canvas.renderAll(); 
    });
}


// ---------------------------
// set up canvas

var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

var path = new fabric.Path('M 0 0 L 150 50 L 120 150 z');
path.set({
  left: 170,
  top: 30,
  fill: 'rgba(0, 128, 0, 0.5)',
  stroke: '#000',
  strokeWidth: 4,
  strokeLineCap: 'square',
  angle: 65
});
canvas.add(path);
canvas.setActiveObject(path);

var circle = new fabric.Circle({
  left: 370,
  top: 30,
  radius: 45,
  fill: 'blue',
  scaleX: 1.5,
  angle: 30
});
canvas.add(circle);


canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
  var setCoords = obj.setCoords.bind(obj);
  obj.on({
    moving: setCoords,
    scaling: setCoords,
    rotating: setCoords
  });
});


canvas.on('after:render', function() {
 canvas.contextContainer.strokeStyle = 'red';
  
 canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
      
  getImageData(obj.toDataURL())
    .then(function(data) {     
        var boundRect = obj.getBoundingRect();
        var realBound = scanPixels(data);                
        canvas.contextContainer.strokeRect(
     boundRect.left + realBound.x1, 
         boundRect.top + realBound.y1, 
         realBound.x2 - realBound.x1, 
         realBound.y2 - realBound.y1
        );    
    });           

 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/3.6.3/fabric.min.js"></script>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
<button onclick="alignLeft()">align left (default)</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button onclick="alignLeftbyBoundRect()">align left (by bounding rect)</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<button onclick="alignRealLeft()">align REAL left (by pixel)</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<p></p>
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="250" style="border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); touch-action: none; user-select: none;" class="lower-canvas"></canvas>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Not sure what is being aligned here, or the red squares.

Comment: I created a fiddle and drawed the real bounding box with green for you: https://jsfiddle.net/1xh6bk80/2/

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm missing something, but none of those boxes are the ones that I was after. See the red boxes in the last set of images in my original question...

Comment: Ehh! It seems it doesn't work properly in Chrome, only in Firefox! Sorry! I'll try to fix that and get back to you later!

Comment: The update works (`toDataURL()` method), but would there be a performance issue if this were to be called after every canvas modification? Basically I want to report actual dimensions dynamically to the user.

Comment: @DivPusher Your original answer now works in Chrome. I'm not sure when Chrome was updated to include a working `getBBox()` but this approach seems to be much more robust than the original accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

So the getBoundingBox is a method of the Object class of fabricjs.
Nothing stops you from rewriting this method for each shape of which you can think of.

I ll start with circle and triangle, i'll let you imagine polygon. It gets harder and harder when shapes are paths or when circle is scaled as an ellipse.

Circle is the hardest.
I sampled the circle at 30, 60, 90 degrees for all the quadrants. still is not perfect. You may need to increase sampling or find a better formula (maybe sample every 15 degrees will make the trick ).

Triangle is the easier since it has 3 points of interest.

Polygon is derived from triangle, nothing difficult here.

```
fabric.Circle.prototype.getBoundingRect = function() {
  var matrix = this.calcTransformMatrix();
  var points = [{x:-this.width/2, y:0}, {x:this.width/2, y:0}, {x:0, y: -this.height/2}, {x: 0, y: this.height/2}, {x: 0, y: -this.height/2}, {x: 0.433 * this.width, y: this.height/4}, {x: -0.433 * this.width, y: this.height/4}, {y: 0.433 * this.height, x: this.width/4}, {y: -0.433 * this.height, x: this.width/4}, {y: -0.433 * this.height, x: -this.width/4}, {y: 0.433 * this.height, x: -this.width/4}, {x: 0.433 * this.width, y: -this.height/4}, {x: -0.433 * this.width, y: -this.height/4}];
  points = points.map(function(p) {
     return fabric.util.transformPoint(p, matrix);
  });
  return fabric.util.makeBoundingBoxFromPoints(points);
}

fabric.Triangle.prototype.getBoundingRect = function() {
  var matrix = this.calcTransformMatrix();
  var points = [{x:-this.width/2, y:this.height/2}, {x:this.width/2, y:this.height/2}, {x:0, y: -this.height/2}, {x: 0, y: 0}];
  points = points.map(function(p) {
     return fabric.util.transformPoint(p, matrix);
  });
  return fabric.util.makeBoundingBoxFromPoints(points);
}

fabric.Polygon.prototype.getBoundingRect = function() {
  var matrix = this.calcTransformMatrix();
  var points = this.points;
  var offsetX = this.pathOffset.x;
  var offsetY = this.pathOffset.y;
      points = points.map(function(p) {
         return fabric.util.transformPoint({x: p.x - offsetX , y: p.y -
 offsetY}, matrix);
      });
      return fabric.util.makeBoundingBoxFromPoints(points);
    }
```

```js
$(function () 
{
    fabric.util.makeBoundingBoxFromPoints = function(points) {
      var minX = fabric.util.array.min(points, 'x'),
          maxX = fabric.util.array.max(points, 'x'),
          width = Math.abs(minX - maxX),
          minY = fabric.util.array.min(points, 'y'),
          maxY = fabric.util.array.max(points, 'y'),
          height = Math.abs(minY - maxY);

      return {
        left: minX,
        top: minY,
        width: width,
        height: height
      };
    };

    fabric.Circle.prototype.getBoundingRect = function() {
      var matrix = this.calcTransformMatrix();
      var points = [{x:-this.width/2, y:0}, {x:this.width/2, y:0}, {x:0, y: -this.height/2}, {x: 0, y: this.height/2}, {x: 0, y: -this.height/2}, {x: 0.433 * this.width, y: this.height/4}, {x: -0.433 * this.width, y: this.height/4}, {y: 0.433 * this.height, x: this.width/4}, {y: -0.433 * this.height, x: this.width/4}, {y: -0.433 * this.height, x: -this.width/4}, {y: 0.433 * this.height, x: -this.width/4}, {x: 0.433 * this.width, y: -this.height/4}, {x: -0.433 * this.width, y: -this.height/4}];
      points = points.map(function(p) {
         return fabric.util.transformPoint(p, matrix);
      });
      return fabric.util.makeBoundingBoxFromPoints(points);
    }
    
    fabric.Triangle.prototype.getBoundingRect = function() {
      var matrix = this.calcTransformMatrix();
      var points = [{x:-this.width/2, y:this.height/2}, {x:this.width/2, y:this.height/2}, {x:0, y: -this.height/2}, {x: 0, y: 0}];
      points = points.map(function(p) {
         return fabric.util.transformPoint(p, matrix);
      });
      return fabric.util.makeBoundingBoxFromPoints(points);
    }

    fabric.Polygon.prototype.getBoundingRect = function() {
      var matrix = this.calcTransformMatrix();
      var points = this.points;
      var offsetX = this.pathOffset.x;
      var offsetY = this.pathOffset.y;
      points = points.map(function(p) {
         return fabric.util.transformPoint({x: p.x - offsetX , y: p.y -
 offsetY}, matrix);
      });
      return fabric.util.makeBoundingBoxFromPoints(points);
    }

    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

    canvas.add(new fabric.Triangle({
      left: 50,
      top: 50,
      fill: '#FF0000',
      width: 50,
      height: 50,
      angle : 30
    }));

    canvas.add(new fabric.Circle({
      left: 250,
      top: 50,
      fill: '#00ff00',
      radius: 50,
      angle : 30
    }));

    canvas.add(new fabric.Polygon([
      {x: 185, y: 0},
      {x: 250, y: 100},
      {x: 385, y: 170},
      {x: 0, y: 245} ], {
        left: 450,
        top: 50,
        fill: '#0000ff',
        angle : 30
      }));

    canvas.on("after:render", function(opt) 
    { 
        canvas.contextContainer.strokeStyle = '#FF0000';
        canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) 
        {
            var bound = obj.getBoundingRect();
            if(bound)
            {
                canvas.contextContainer.strokeRect(
                    bound.left + 0.5,
                    bound.top + 0.5,
                    bound.width,
                    bound.height
                );
            }                
        });
    });

    canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.6/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="c" width="800" height="600"></canvas><br/>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I've modified it to run as it was grumbling when trying to render the red box for the shapes with no getBoundingRect body. I was kind of hoping that I had just overlooked something and that this code was already there. Perhaps a good inclusion for the future?

Comment: Sorry to be a pain. I've just noticed that it doesn't work when the circle is skewed...

Comment: i need to finish the answer. a skewed circle is the hardest case. i need some time, i m working now. The less point you have, the harder is to create the current box. ideally we should divide the circle in 4 beizers and some complicated stuff. it goes beyond what i can do in an answer, but i will try to leave meaningfull hints

Comment: Added triangle @LeeTaylor

Comment: The triangle i would say beautifully respond to the scaling and skewing

Comment: Yes, this is great. I think I may be scratching my head with rotated ellipses!

Comment: Many thanks for your hard work on this answer and for fabricJS!

Comment: That fix to makeBoundingBoxFromPoints i think it should go in the library

Comment: Downside: Try selecting all objects, and rotate the group. Observe the bounds for the group doesn't precisely match the actual pixels of shapes. For this use case, [DivPusher's updated answer below works](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61870615/4378314).